# How to open file in vscode from terminal with cursor at last line?

Tags: bash, shell, visual-studio-code, scripting, ubuntu-20.04

I am working on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
I wrote a bash script which created a `.sh` file with boiler plate lines

> #! /bin/bash
> # this file was created by create_script.sh

and opens it in vscode. However, when the file opens, the cursor is at the start of the file.
The command I used was`code $fname`.
In `$ code --help`, I found the following

> `-g --goto <file:line[:character]> Open a file at the path on the specified line and  character position.`

So I suppose I can just do `code -g $fname:3:1`. (Which I tested and it works)
But I was wondering if there is some option to open with cursor at last character of file so that I could do so for any file without using something other like `wc -l`. I thought negative indexing would work but it didn't.

Comment: Try 'G' instead of the line number. That goes to the last line in vi. I apologize, but I don't have a linux machine to test it out on.

Comment: It gives `Warning: 'G' is not in the list of known options, but still passed to Electron/Chromium.` Thanks for responding though.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help. Only other thought is to set it to some massive number. Just to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer given by [gnodab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13253198/gnodab).
Use a massive number in place of line in option `-g file:line:character`.